# Alerts: How to assert a given paragraph

Tags: webdriver, junit

Using WebDriver and JUnit 4.11.
I'm attempting to find an alert and assert the body of the alert paragraph.

My code is:

```
@Test
public void dNameField(){

    WebElement nameField = chrome.findElementByCssSelector("input.t-textInput-A[name='name']");
    nameField.clear();

    List<WebElement> elements;
    elements = chrome.findElements(By.className("logMessage.error"));

    Set<String> foundAlerts = new HashSet<String>();

    for(WebElement e : elements){
        foundAlerts.add(e.getTagName());
    }

    Assert.assertTrue("This should be an error message", foundAlerts.contains("An error has occurred : Value must be a Number."));
```

I receive a `java.lang.AssertionError:` in the stacktrace.

In the DOM before an alert is thrown this is this class which holds all the error logs that are produced in the session. `<ul class="logContainer t-logs-A">`

Once I have managed to simulate an alert by clearing all data from a particular field, the alert is thrown in this class

```
<ul class="logContainer t-logs-A">
<li class="logMessage error" id="l1392048208775" style="display: none;">
<header>
<p>error!</p>
<p class="closeBtn"></p>
</header>
<p>An error has occurred : Value must be a Number.</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

The `id` is dynamically created so when I attempt to 'copy xpath' I'm supplied with `//*[@id="l1392048208775"]/p` which is no good.

The alerts that are thrown all remain in the DOM as I can visibly see them, although they are hidden as they fade out from the UI after a couple of seconds.

Any suggestions on how to go about this, please?

Comment: Have you tried changing your CSS selector to `.logMessage.error`?

Comment: Hi @user246 I tried placing a dot before the CSS selector and that did nothing, as I suspected it would. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the selenium Alert switchto method and gettext?

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
String text = alert.getText(); 
alert.dimiss();
```